# Meaning of "pragmatic"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *pragmatic* in this example?

> Another C construct, the #pragma
>   directive, is used to instruct the
>   compiler to use **pragmatic** or
>   implementation-dependent features. A
>   most notable user of this directive is
>   OpenMP.

According to online dictionary, *pragmatic* means:

> Dealing with things sensibly and
>   realistically in a way that is based
>   on practical rather than theoretical
>   considerations.

But I can't see how this explains the word in the example above.

Comment: The definition at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pragma makes an attempt at explaining this :)

Comment: Why is it called pragmatic? Is it related to its original meaning?

Comment: Though many here could most likely give rational answers to this question, strictly, I would say it is off-topic.

Comment: This is really a programming question; more specifically, it is a programming language-specific question. A *pragma* is a compiler directive, and I suspect that the example is using "pragmatic" in a non-standard, CS-specific way.

Comment: Vote to reopen. If 'pragmatic' is a Term of Art in Computer Science, then that's a fact about English Language usage, even if the meaning of that Term of Art is a CS question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone with better knowledge of this directive might have a more specific answer, but I think the context answers the question you are asking:

> ...is used to instruct the compiler to use pragmatic or implementation-dependent features.

That is, "pragmatic" in this context means "implementation-dependent." A `pragma` directive gives the compiler directions on how to interact with a specific architecture, for instance. Pragmas are a means to accomplish something efficiently (in a practical or *pragmatic* way) that might have a better theoretical solution.

In contrast, "implementation-independent" features are the *ideal* (non-pragmatic) way to design code.  By using "implementation-independent" features, the code is theoretically self-contained and universally interoperable.  This theoretical ideal is difficult in practice because of the heterogeneity of platforms and the diversity of interface methods.  Using a directive that allows you to adapt code directly to a specific implementation is a lot more practical than trying to design something that is generic enough to work with every implementation.

Wiktionary has an entry on [pragma](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pragma)s that might shed some light.

Comment: Thanks! So how to understand "implementation-independent" as theoretic, i.e., non-pragmatic?

Comment: @Tim: Not necessarily. I would say that implementation-independent would be _ideal_, that's the contrast.

Comment: @Tim I edited my answer to incorporate implementation-independent features.  Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of doing what you need to do (in practical terms) rather than what the C standard strictly allows you to do.

Suppose you want to put a very short delay into your code.  You might write something like this:

```
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        ;
}
```

It looks nice and simple; just repeatedly increment a variable and then throw it away.  The trouble is that a sensible optimiser will spot that this code does exactly nothing and throw the whole thing away, leaving you with no delay.  You could switch the optimiser off when you run the compiler, but you don't want to do that because it makes the rest of your program larger and less efficient.

If you stick rigidly to the standard, you are a bit stuck at this point.  You could put this snippet in a file of its own and compile it separately with the optimiser off.  That would be a more theoretically satisfying answer, but it comes with maintenance nightmares, the overhead of an extra function call, and so on.

The *pragmatic* answer, if your compiler supports such a thing, is to stick

```
#pragma optimisation_off
/* code here */
#pragma optimisation_on
```

around the code you want left alone.

(The real answer is to declare `i` as `volatile` or better yet not to write delays with spin loops, but let's ignore that for the sake of example.)

Comment: Great example, Rhodri.  I was thinking along these lines, but my C is about fifteen years rusty.